# use of undeclared identifier in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

I'm making an simple game, and Xcode finds a bug says that there is a "use of undeclared identifier 'gameLoop'". How can I fix this?

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    gameState = kStateRunning;


    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0/60 target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    rockVelocity = CGPointMake (0, 0); 
    gravity = CGPointMake (0, kGravity);    

- (void)gameLoop {
    if (gameState == kStateRunning)
    {
        [self gameStatePlayNormal];
    }
    else if (gameState == kStateGameOver)
    {

    }
}

(void)gameStatePlayNormal {
    rockVelocity.y += gravity.y;

    rock.center = CGPoint(rock.center.x + ballVelocity.x,rock.center.y + rockVelocity.y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a closing bracket after your viewDidLoad method. Please note that methods in Objective C need a - or + in front of them.

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
gameState = kStateRunning;


[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0/60 target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
rockVelocity = CGPointMake (0, 0); 
gravity = CGPointMake (0, kGravity);   
}
 - (void)gameLoop {
   if (gameState == kStateRunning)
   {
       [self gameStatePlayNormal];
   }
    else if (gameState == kStateGameOver)
    {

    }
}

-(void)gameStatePlayNormal {
    rockVelocity.y += gravity.y;

    rock.center = CGPoint(rock.center.x + ballVelocity.x,rock.center.y + rockVelocity.y);}
```

Comment: You need to say -(void)viewDidLoad instead of (void)viewDidLoad

Comment: thanks but it now says use of undeclared identifier 'gameStatePlayNormal'

Comment: That's all I can do, make sure all of your opening brackets have closing brackets and all of your method declarations have the correct syntax. Part of programming is learning to diagnose and fix problems yourself.